# QSettings::IniFormat values with "," returned as QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qsettings

I am using `QSettings` to parse an ini file: `QSettings cfg(path, QSettings::IniFormat);`

When I obtain a value `QVariant qv = cfg.value("title");` containing a comma the variant contains a `QStringList` instead of a `QString`

```
title=foo => QString
title=foo,bar => QStringList
```

How can I always get strings, or at least obtain the original line ( `title=foo,bar` ) ?

Comment: myStringList.join(',')?

Comment: Agree. You should probably also point out that QSettings treats the comma as a separator which is really not obvious even looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least two ways to address this issue, all of them presented below:

#### test.ini

```
title="foo,bar"
title_unquoted=foo,bar
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QSettings>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QSettings settings("test.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
    // Original issue
    qDebug() << settings.value("title_unquoted");
    // 1st solution: join the strings
    qDebug() << settings.value("title").toStringList().join(',');
    // 2nd solution: use quotes in the ini file
    qDebug() << settings.value("title");
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
QVariant(QStringList, ("foo", "bar"))
"foo,bar"
QVariant(QString, "foo,bar")
```

In other words, use quotes for strings with special characters or join the strings manually in the list. The former is far better if it is under your control as you usually ought to aim for proper quoting when using "special" characters in strings.